# render latex with mathjax in only one div

Tags: javascript, latex, mathjax

I just spent one hour on this problem and I can't seem to find a solution.

I'm loading MathJax without configuration so that I configure it myself:

```
<script data-cfasync="false" type="text/javascript" async
        src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.2/MathJax.js">
</script>
```

and here's my configuration. It fails to not render what is in `<div class="comment">`

```
 <script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
    MathJax.Hub.Config({
    jax: ["input/TeX","input/MathML","input/AsciiMath","output/CommonHTML"],
    extensions: ["tex2jax.js","mml2jax.js","asciimath2jax.js","MathMenu.js","MathZoom.js","AssistiveMML.js", "a11y/accessibility-menu.js"],
    TeX: {
    extensions: ["AMSmath.js","AMSsymbols.js","noErrors.js","noUndefined.js"]
      },
    tex2jax: {
        inlineMath: [['$','$'], ['\\(','\\)']],
        ignoreClass: "comment"
      }
    });
  </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like I found the answer. In addition to `tex2jax` ignoring this class, `asciimath2jax` also has to ignore this class.

Mathjax is configuration hell.

```
    MathJax.Hub.Config({
    jax: ["input/TeX","input/MathML","input/AsciiMath","output/CommonHTML"],
    extensions: ["tex2jax.js","mml2jax.js","asciimath2jax.js","MathMenu.js","MathZoom.js","AssistiveMML.js", "a11y/accessibility-menu.js"],
    TeX: {
    extensions: ["AMSmath.js","AMSsymbols.js","noErrors.js","noUndefined.js"]
    },

    asciimath2jax: {
        ignoreClass: "comment"
    },
    tex2jax: {
        inlineMath: [['$','$'], ['\\(','\\)']],
        ignoreClass: "comment"
      }
    });
```